# Is it possible in Qt to stop the execution of a slot in some point until some condition occurs somewhere else? Would condition variables work fine?

Tags: c++, qt, synchronization

I have my slot that does some stuff. Under certain conditions this slot may require to be stopped until some condition occurs somewhere else. How can I achieve this? Yes, of course I could decouple the logic in two slots and arrange connections properly but I was looking for some more elegant work-around. Condition variables came in my mind but, as a newby at using Qt, I don't know whether they would work or not in that I didn't explicitly declare any thread class.

Comment: *"[..] this slot may require to be stopped [..]"* - what do you mean?

Comment: @vahancho It has to be stopped because it is possible that it has to wait some other conditions to occur before ti can resume its execution. It is not important why, it depends on my application requirements

Comment: You can use standard multithreading mechanisms such as semaphore, atomics or mutextes.

Comment: Assuming that you have a signal that will be emitted when the condition becomes true, If the condition is false, you can just connect this signal to the slot and disconnect it as soon as the slot is called. I would suggest you put a lambda expression or something in between the signal and the slot instead of connecting them directly.

Answer (score 0):

any QObject has a method for blocking signals that works like a switch allowing to turn OFF - ON the signals the object emit.

here is the doc for this feature:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#blockSignals

> If block is true, signals emitted by this object are blocked (i.e., emitting a signal will not invoke anything connected to it). If block is false, no such blocking will occur.

you can call it as

for turning OFF the signals:

```
 ui->myButton->blockSignals(true);
```

and for turning ON the signals:

```
 ui->myButton->blockSignals(false);
```

Comment: This is a very good answer. But to a different question. :)